# Altering the cell content at pandas style

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to display a text within each cell of a table while utilizing the style.background_gradient function to apply color by another table.

For a clearer illustration of this question, I've provided the relevant code snippet below:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from faker import Faker


fake = Faker()

# Sample data
text = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, 15, [4, 3]), columns=list('ABC'))
text = text.applymap(fake.text)

# Style color should be by this importancy value
importancy = text.copy()
importancy[:] = np.random.randint(0, 100, text.shape)
importancy = importancy.astype(int)

# Outputs that i want to combine
text
importancy.style.background_gradient(cmap='Greens').format('')
```

Here's the text table that I want to add the below color to it:

```
    A           B           C
0   Whose.      Health.     Pass black.
1   Only want.  Most.       Seek.
2   Road.       Indeed.     Certain.
3   Explain.    Son high.   Ahead.
```

And the expected color representation is as follows:

[image]

**I've already attempted few approaches:**

*export*

Using style.export(), but this re-evaluates the color when applied to another table.

*Modify data attribute*

Another option is modifying the data content within the style by:

```py
style = importancy.style.background_gradient(cmap='Greens')
style.data[:] = text
```

However, altering the data causes the color evaluation to be re-run.

*HTML table*

Another approach is building an HTML color table and using the apply function.

You can achieve this using the following code snippet:

```py
styled_table = text.style.apply(lambda x: color_table, axis=None)
```

where one of the cells at color_table can be 'background-color: #98faa2'.

Nevertheless, I'm currently lacking a method to acquire the style configuration as plain text, as demonstrated in the example.
I know I can use some other packages to create gradient color based on values, but gradient color is just an example for style option, and I want to export all the coloring of the style, including coloring min/max/null etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the dataframes you provided:

```py
text
```

Output:

[image]

```py
importancy.style.background_gradient(cmap='Greens').format('')
```

Output:

[image]

Here is one way to do it with Python standard library's [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module and Pandas [to_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_html.html) method:

```py
import re

# Save html of both dataframes
with open("text.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(text.style.to_html())
with open("importancy.html", "w") as f:
    f.write(importancy.style.background_gradient(cmap="Greens").to_html())

# Edit 'importancy.html' to replace strings with the ones from 'text.html'
new_lines = []
with open("text.html", mode="r") as src:
    with open("importancy.html", mode="r") as dest:
        pairs = {}
        for line in src.readlines():
            # r"row\d+_col\d+" means "row1_col1" for instance
            # r">(.*)<" means any string beginning with ">" and ending with "<"
            if re.findall(r"row\d+_col\d+", line):
                row_col = re.findall(r"row\d+_col\d+", line)[0]
                text_to_copy = re.findall(r">(.*)<", line)[0]
                pairs[row_col] = text_to_copy
        for other_line in dest.readlines():
            for row_col, text_to_copy in pairs.items():
                if row_col in other_line:
                    other_line = re.sub(
                        pattern=r">(.*)<", repl=f">{text_to_copy}<", string=other_line
                    )
            new_lines.append(other_line)

# Save edited html file
with open(r"new_text.html", mode="w") as f:
    f.writelines(new_lines)
```

Then, in another cell of your Jupyter notebook:

```py
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML(filename="new_text.html")
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Impressive workaround! 
A bit complicated but works great.